# SQL - Output column based on latest date

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like the below. I have the first 4 columns. The last 2 are the ones I want to add. I'm on Teradata.

```
custid  channel activity_date   close_date  lastchannel days_before_close
11      email   2-Jan-16        3-Feb-16    meeting     28
11      call    3-Jan-16        3-Feb-16    meeting     28
11      mail    4-Jan-16        3-Feb-16    meeting     28
11      email   5-Jan-16        3-Feb-16    meeting     28
11      meeting 6-Jan-16        3-Feb-16    meeting     28
```

1) lastchannel: I want to output the channel name for the max  activity date. So in the example above, I want the new column to say "meeting" in all rows.

2) the days between the close date and the last activity date: In this case, the days between Feb 3 and Jan 6 is 28.

I tried the below but I get a error saying I need a succeeds or precedes statement somewhere.

`first_value(channel) over (partition by cust_id, activity_date order by activity_date desc) as lastchannel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as Gordon's, based on your comment you might want this:

```
first_value(case when activity_date <= close_date then channel end ignore nulls) 
over (partition by cust_id
      order by activity_date desc) as lastchannel
```

And the 2nd is

```
close_date - max(activity_date) over (partition by cust_id) as days_before_close
```

Based on your comment:

```
close_date - max(case when activity_date <= close_date then activity_date end)
             over (partition by cust_id) as days_before_close
```

Comment: Hi, how would I put the same where condition on #2? i.e. I need the days_before_close for the last activity before close

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this logic to work:

```
first_value(channel) over (partition by cust_id
                           order by activity_date desc
                          ) as lastchannel
```

Perhaps you need an explicit windowing clause:

```
first_value(channel) over (partition by cust_id
                           order by activity_date desc
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                          ) as lastchannel
```

Or even:

```
first_value(channel) over (partition by cust_id
                           order by activity_date desc
                           rows between current row and current row
                          ) as lastchannel
```

If this version works.

Comment: thanks, the first one works. I need to put a where condition like this but this gives me a error `first_value(channel) over (partition by cust_id where activity_date <= close_date order by activity_date desc) as lastchannel`